# How can I permanently ignore a database column in my ActiveRecord::Base class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a legacy database which I'm trying to model using Rails. One of the tables has a column named `attributes`, which is a name reserved by Rails I think.

Here is the SQL for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `album` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `artist` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `gid` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `modpending` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `attributes` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  ...
);
```

Here's my ActiveRecord class:

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "album"
  belongs_to :artist
  has_many :tracks, :through => :album_tracks
end
```

Here's what happens when I try to instantiate an instance:

```
hornairs@bishop:~/Sites/logdb (master *)$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.3)
no such file to load -- irbtools
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > x = Album.find_by_name("Champ")
 => #<Album id: 969139, artist: 354493, name: "Champ", gid: "15a9a4b8-9dd9-4f6f-b4e9-7c69948af88f", modpending: 0, attributes: 1100, page: 143735328, language: 120, script: 28, modpending_lang: nil, quality: -1, modpending_qual: 0> 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > x.name
ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError: attributes_before_type_cast is defined by ActiveRecord
  from /Users/hornairs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@logdb/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:23:in `instance_method_already_implemented?'
  from /Users/hornairs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@logdb/gems/activemodel-3.0.3/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:263:in `block (2 levels) in define_attribute_methods'
  from /Users/hornairs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@logdb/gems/activemodel-3.0.3/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:262:in `each'
  from /Users/hornairs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@logdb/gems/activemodel-3.0.3/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:262:in `block in define_attribute_methods'
  from /Users/hornairs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@logdb/gems/activemodel-3.0.3/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:261:in `each'
  from /Users/hornairs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@logdb/gems/activemodel-3.0.3/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:261:in `define_attribute_methods'
  from /Users/hornairs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@logdb/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:13:in `define_attribute_methods'
  from /Users/hornairs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@logdb/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:41:in `method_missing'
  from /Users/hornairs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@logdb/gems/thwart-0.0.4/lib/thwart/canable.rb:27:in `method_missing'
  from (irb):2
  from /Users/hornairs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@logdb/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
  from /Users/hornairs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@logdb/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
  from /Users/hornairs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@logdb/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
  from script/rails:6:in `require'
  from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
ruby-1.9.2-p0 >
```

It looks as if the `attributes` name is reserved, so I'd like to find some way to ignore it for all queries and have AR ignore it when reflecting on the schema to define the model class. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the solution but I found a thread with someone having the same issue: <http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=41399>. Not sure it'll help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved this using a combination of stuff from Robin's link and some other SO answers

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "album"

  class << self
    def instance_method_already_implemented?(method_name)
      return true if method_name =~ /^attributes/
      super
    end
  end

  belongs_to :artist
  has_many :tracks, :through => :album_tracks
end
```

Did the trick. I used a big sweeping change to return true without throwing an error for all methods starting with `attributes`, and I don't think its caused any problems elsewhere.

Answer (score 9):

```
  class << self
     def instance_method_already_implemented?(method_name)
      return true if method_name =~ /^attributes/
      super
    end
  end
```

This patch is fine and was working for me mostly, but when you check something like 
Album.column_names and Album.columns.collect(&:name) you would still get all columns.
Also this would fail.

```
 a = Album.last
 a = Album.new(a.attributes)
```

To have rails fully ignore a column you could do this.

```
 class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name "album"
    ## --------------------- Ignore columns patch ------
    @@ignore_column_pattern = /^column_one|^column_two/

    class << self
      alias :all_columns :columns
      def columns 
        @columns_filt ||= all_columns.reject { |col| col.name =~ @@ignore_column_pattern } 
      end 
    end

    alias :all_attribute_names :attribute_names
    def attribute_names
      @attr_names_filt ||= all_attribute_names.reject { |att| att =~ @@ignore_column_pattern }
    end
    ## ------------------- / Ignore columns patch ------
    belongs_to :artist
    has_many :tracks, :through => :album_tracks
  end
```

Also I used an array to store the columns I didn't want but you could still use the regex way too! Now the only way that you can find out about the column is using connection ie.

```
Album.connection.columns("albums").collect(&:name)
```

Answer (score 5):

(This is an old question but still figures in Google so I'll add a belated answer)

I've found the best way to restrict data loaded by an ActiveRecord model is to create a database view that only contains the columns you wish to load. You can point your ActiveRecord model at the constrained view using ActiveRecord's [table_name](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods/table_name) method. Native SQL tools can still manipulate the underlying table, but ActiveRecord will only see (and consequently load) the columns explicitly included in the view.