# Rails sequence column on Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, sequence

I followed this [mini-tutorial successfully](http://msquaredwebsvc.blogspot.pt/2013/01/create-postgresql-sequence-for-ruby-on.html) to have a column (car_code) in my table (cars) to work like a sequence (using postgreSQL database).

As Result I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE Cars
(
 id serial NOT NULL,
 created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
 updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
 car_date timestamp without time zone,
 car_code integer DEFAULT nextval('car_code_sequence'::regclass),
 CONSTRAINT cars_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id )
 )
```

My insert statement works fine:

```
INSERT INTO cars(created_at, updated_at, car_date) VALUES (now(), now(), now());
--1|Date|Date|Date|2 <--using my car_code_sequence
```

Unfortunately, when i invoke a "create" operation in a "car_controller the rails application generate this statement:

```
INSERT INTO "cars" ("created_at", "car_code", "car_date", "updated_at") 
VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id" [
  ["created_at", Mon, 04 Mar 2013 14:39:55 UTC +00:00],
  ["car_code", nil], 
  ["car_date", Mon, 04 Mar 2013 14:39:55 UTC +00:00],
  ["updated_at", Mon, 04 Mar 2013 14:39:55 UTC +00:00]]
```

So, my question is:

Who can I change the Car Model to exclude the column "car_code" from insert statement (but keeping the "car_code" in database), i.e., to have the same behaviour as "id").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this code at car model:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  ## --------------------- Ignore columns patch ------
  @@ignore_column_pattern = /^car_code/

  class << self
    alias :all_columns :columns
    def columns 
      @columns_filt ||= all_columns.reject { |col| col.name =~ @@ignore_column_pattern } 
    end 
  end

  alias :all_attribute_names :attribute_names
  def attribute_names
    @attr_names_filt ||= all_attribute_names.reject { |att| att =~ @@ignore_column_pattern }
  end
  ## ------------------- / Ignore columns patch ------
end
```

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10319903/1042324